# Анимация по таймеру javascript

Tags: javascript, анимация, функции

Вопрос заключается в том что бы написать на чистом javascript код который позволит каждые определенные n секунд добавлять и удалять класс. Вот код собственно с которым я работаю, но метод который я использовал дает сбой и время сбивается. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
<script>
    var scaleElem = document.getElementById('par_mak');

            setInterval(myMethod_one, 6000);
            function myMethod_one( )
            {
              scaleElem.classList.add('infi_anim');
            }
            setInterval(myMethod_second, 12000);
            function myMethod_second( )
            {
              scaleElem.classList.remove('infi_anim');
            }
</script>
```

Задумка в том что бы элемент двигался с определенной периодичностью, для привлечения внимания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если время должно быть одинаково между добавлением/удалением класса, можно просто создать флаг, который будет указывать, добавить или удалить класс.

```js
var scaleElem = document.getElementById('par_mak');
var addClass = true;

setInterval(addClassToScaleElem, 1000);

function addClassToScaleElem( ) {
  var classList = scaleElem.classList;
  if (addClass) {
    classList.add('infi_anim');
  } else {
    classList.remove('infi_anim');
  }
  addClass = !addClass;
}
```

```css
#par_mak {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.infi_anim {
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="par_mak"></div>
```

Если разное, то можно опять же в одном методе отчищать его -  `clearInterval(interval)` и заново запускать - `interval = setInterval(addClassToScaleElem, counter);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var scaleElem = document.getElementById('par_mak');
setInterval(myMethod_one, 3000);
function myMethod_one( )
{
  scaleElem.classList.add('infi_anim');
  setTimeout(function(){ scaleElem.classList.remove('infi_anim'); }, 300);
}
```

```css
.red-square
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}

.infi_anim
{
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-square" id="par_mak">
</div>
```